# Create rule for sets of duplicates in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, boolean

I have a large dataframe with different duplicate values. How can I iterate through these different sets of duplicates and set column values accordingly?

For example, let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(['2021-1-1', '2017-2-1', '2016-5-1', '2020-6-1', '2020-11-1', '2012-4-1'])
animals = pd.Series(['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'fish'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'DoB' : dates, 'Animal' : animals})

df[r'Born in 2020?'] = df['DoB'].apply(lambda x: True if x.year==2020 else False)

df

    DoB         Animal  Born in 2020?
0   2021-01-01  cat     False
1   2017-02-01  dog     False
2   2016-05-01  dog     False
3   2020-06-01  cat     True
4   2020-11-01  fish    True
5   2012-04-01  fish    False
```

I want to keep the oldest duplicate of each animal, and fill a column titled "Duplicate born in 2020?".

Essentially, before dropping duplicates, how can I create a script that says "if the 'Born in 2020' value for one of the duplicates for each animal is True, then set 'True' for all duplicates in 'Duplicate born in 2020' column".?

Ultimately, the dataframe I want to end up with would look like this:

```
    DoB         Animal  Duplicate born in 2020?  
0   2020-06-01  cat     True
2   2016-05-01  dog     False
5   2012-04-01  fish    True
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply another `lambda` function where you can check for the "duplicates born in 2020". Thereafter just use `drop_duplicates` function from pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) .

```
df[r'Duplicate Born in 2020?'] = df['Animal'].apply(lambda x: True if (True in df.loc[df['Animal']==x,['Born in 2020?']]['Born in 2020?'].tolist()) else False)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Animal'],keep='last', inplace=True)
df.drop(['Born in 2020?'], axis=1, inplace=True)  #remoe unwanted columns
df
    DoB         Animal  Duplicate Born in 2020?
2   2016-05-01  dog     False
3   2020-06-01  cat     True
5   2012-04-01  fish    True
```

I guess this was your final ask.

Comment: That deals with half of the problem. We still need something that essentially says "if the 'Born in 2020' value for one of the duplicates in each set is True, then set 'True' for all duplicates in 'Duplicate born in 2020' column". How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

For This condition:
We still need something that essentially says "if the 'Born in 2020' value for one of the duplicates in each set is True, then set 'True' for all duplicates in 'Duplicate born in 2020' column".

Use boolean masking,`groupby()` method and `assign()` method:

```
condition=(df[df['Born in 2020?']==True].groupby('Animal')['Born in 2020?'].size()>=1)
df['Born in 2020?']=df.set_index('Animal')['Born in 2020?'].to_frame().assign(result=condition)['result'].values
```

For keeping oldest duplicate of Animal column

use `sort_values()` and `drop_duplicates()` method:

```
df=df.sort_values('DoB').drop_duplicates(subset=['Animal'],ignore_index=True)
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
    DoB        Animal   Born in 2020?
0   2012-04-01  fish    True
1   2016-05-01  dog     True
2   2020-06-01  cat     True
```

Comment: That deals with half of the problem. We still need something that essentially says "if the 'Born in 2020' value for one of the duplicates in each set is True, then set 'True' for all duplicates in 'Duplicate born in 2020' column". How could I do this?

Comment: Updated answer for this condition....kindly have a look **:)**