# Validation of a conditional rule in a column and duplication in another

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database of products and I have to validate if the product ID repeats in a column and also validate if it's 'True' or 'False' in another column. Then set all to 'True' if at least one of the duplicated rows are 'True'.

I found a way in this link: [Create rule for sets of duplicates in a Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164011/create-rule-for-sets-of-duplicates-in-a-pandas-dataframe) using the second answer, but it's spending too much time doing the process in my database, something like 8min.

Does someone know how to do that in a faster way?

Example:

```
ID Active 
01 False
01 False
01 True
02 False
02 False
03 True
03 False
03 False
```

And it should be like this in the end:

```
ID Active 
01 True
01 True
01 True
02 False
02 False
03 True
03 True
03 True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conveniently use `max` in a [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['Active'] = df.groupby('ID')['Active'].transform('max')
```

Or `any` that is a bit faster:

```
df['Active'] = df.groupby('ID')['Active'].transform('any')
```

Output:

```
   ID  Active
0   1    True
1   1    True
2   1    True
3   2   False
4   2   False
5   3    True
6   3    True
7   3    True
```

Comment: I think 'any' outperforms 'max' with boolean.

Comment: @Scott could be, let me check

Comment: @Scott you were right, but it's still close. 29 vs 33ms on 800K rows, 1.5 vs 2.2 ms on 800 rows

Comment: I'll bet some sort of short-curcuiting is going on there.  First True it stops and returns True.

Comment: @Scott that what I also wondered but shouldn't the short-circuiting be the same in both cases? Assuming max is type-aware and expects True to be the max possible value.